# Vector field over a 3D mesh

Tags: matlab, graphics, 3d, mesh

I am currently writing my own Matlab implementation of a paper from 2003, [Fast Texture Synthesis on Arbitrary Mesh](http://vision.ucsd.edu/kriegman-grp/papers/egsr03.pdf).
Everything is going quite well, except for the rotation part of the similarity transform, which implies the creation of a vector field accross the 3D surface. This is a very important part of the algorithm because it gives a more natural and coherent textural aspect all over the 3D surface.

The problem is, I just have no idea how to do this. [Litterature](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~mdfisher/Data/VectorFieldDesign.pdf) I've found on the subject is quite obscur to me, so I'm now looking for a more pragmatic (and programmatic) way to perform this.

Any idea ?

[EDIT] Just in case that may be relevant, I tried [this code](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28106-texture-patch), which use barycentric interpolation to map a texture image to a 3D mesh. HOWEVER, in the example given texture vertex indices are known beforehand, hence, as far as my understanding goes, I'm still stuck with the rotation part of the similarity transform between the texture image and the 3D mesh. I still **need to create a vector field around the surface**.

Finally, here is the code I wrote, about the texture preprocessing part of Magda and Kriegman algorithm :

```
%% Implementation inspired by the work of Magda & Kriegman(2003), "Fast Texture     Synthesis on Arbitrary Mesh"
function [TextonImage, LUT, TextonBucket] = GenerateTextons( SampleImage, gaussianSize, nbKmeansCenters )

% Create Gaussian kernel
h = fspecial( 'gaussian', gaussianSize );

% Generate feature vectors
FeatureVectors = ComputeFeatureVectors( h, SampleImage );

% Perform k-mean clustering, classify feature vectors (i.e. assign labels)
[IDX,C] = kmeans( FeatureVectors, nbKmeansCenters );

% Create texton texture
LUT = randi( 255, size( C, 1 ), 3 );
[TextonImage, TextonBucket] = CreateTextonTexture( C, SampleImage, LUT, h );

end


function Vectors = ComputeFeatureVectors( Kernel, Image )

offset = floor( size( Kernel, 1 ) / 2 );
vectorsSize = ( size( Image, 1 ) - 2 * offset ) * ( size( Image, 2 ) - 2 * offset );

Vectors = zeros( vectorsSize, size( Kernel, 1 ) * size( Kernel, 1 ) );
kk = 1;

for ii = ( 1 + offset ):( size( Image, 1 ) - offset )
    for jj = ( 1 + offset ):( size( Image, 2 ) - offset )
        temp = Kernel .* double( Image( ii - offset:ii + offset, jj - offset:jj + offset ) );
        Vectors( kk, : ) = reshape( temp, size( Kernel, 1 ) * size( Kernel, 1 ), 1 )';
        kk = kk + 1;
    end
end

end



function [ TextonImage, TextonBucket ] = CreateTextonTexture( Centroids, Image, LUT, Kernel )

offset = floor( size( Kernel, 1 ) / 2 );
TextonImage = zeros( size( Image, 1 ), size( Image, 2 ), 3 );
TextonBucket = struct;
IndexTable = zeros( size( Centroids, 1 ), 1 );

for ii = ( 1 + offset ):(size( Image, 1 ) - offset)
    for jj = ( 1 + offset ):(size( Image, 2 ) - offset)
        temp = Kernel .* double( Image( ii - offset:ii + offset, jj - offset:jj + offset ) );
        Vector = reshape( temp, size( Kernel, 1 ) * size( Kernel, 1 ), 1 )';

        minDist = 10000;
        Index = 0;

        for k=1:size( Centroids, 1 )
            % Calculate distance of test point to training point.
            d = sum( Vector - Centroids( k, : ) ) .^ 2;
            % if smaller...
            if d < minDist
                minDist = d;
                Index = k;
            end
        end

        TextonImage( ii, jj, : ) = LUT( Index, : );
        cellName = strcat('B',num2str(Index));
        IndexTable( Index ) = IndexTable( Index ) + 1;
        TextonBucket.(cellName){ IndexTable( Index ) } = [ jj, ii ];
    end
end

end
```

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried, what is your code, what are your structures, where are you stuck?

Comment: I've tried nothing, because as stated I HAVE NO IDEA HOW TO PERFORM this. Before coding something, don't you think it's a good idea to understand the problem and design some algorithm ?

Comment: Yes I do. And I do that before trying some code, and I try some code before I post here. And you said you are writing your implementation so I thought you might have some code even to show how you are structuring the part that is going quite well. Wasn't my downvote, btw. Anyway, I imagine you'll have another Nx3 matrix defining your vector directions for each point in your surface. Plenty of examples online with searches for `vector field matlab` - even a yahoo answers one if you can stoop that low ;)

Comment: See my edit above. AND I don't want any vector field, I want a vector field which lies around a surface.

Comment: A good starting point, from a couple of the papers linked, is the normal and/or tangential vectors of each face. If you have definitions of the faces, then you have this. Otherwise it will be the differential values in XY(Z) of your mesh points. The papers mention smoothing operations afterwards; some sort of gaussian averaging or even a moving average might do, I don't know if your mesh is linearly spaced or not.

Comment: I have the normal vectors, then I guess I have to choose a direction and compute tangential vectors from that ? How this will propagate all over the mesh ? Thank you.

Comment: One comment in this paper: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/hoppe/lapped.pdf suggests `projecting the global up direction` and their plots of rabbits with field lines seem to suggest the tangent might point from the center of the face to the highest point in each triangle.

Comment: Thank you Hugh, didn't know Praun et al. work. Since my texture is a stochastic one, I will go with global up direction. Thanks again, this is far simpler than other papers about tangential vector fields algorithms I came accross (and which I don't actually need).